# How to determine the unknown molecule using the infrared spectroscopy?

Tags: ir-spectroscopy

> An unknown sample was analysed using infrared spectroscopy. What is
> the compound?

[image]

[image]

So I am having difficulty in using the infrared data to determine the unknown compound. I keep on misinterpreting the information on the Infrared spectrum. According to the answer provided, it is ethanamide. But how? What does the strong and broad range tell you? Is it $2730-3100$ or $3200-3600$? Why can't it be $O-H$?
What about the range between $1500 - 2000$, does that correspond to $C$ double bond $C$ or $C$ double bond $O$?

How can I interpret the diagram correctly? The range seems to overlap it selves?

[image]

Comment: You can't identify an unknown compound by manually analyzing its IR spectra. Computers can do it by pattern matching the unknown spectra to a library of spectra, assuming that the unknown sample is pure. // You could perhaps choose the correct compound from say 4 choices.

Comment: With the information provided it is not possible to identify this moelcule as an amide as the crucial information about the amide C=O and N-H signals is not given. This will provide hte missing information  https://personal.utdallas.edu/~scortes/ochem/OChem_Lab1/recit_notes/ir_presentation.pdf

Comment: @Waylander Sorry, it is a multiple choice question. Mind taking a look again? Thanks

Comment: @MaxW Hi Max, thanks for commenting. It is a multiple choice question, see the update. Many thanks.

Comment: @Negrawh  In future please give us the whole question first time

Answer (score 4):

First, eliminate ethylene (ethene) because the strong absroption from 3200 to 3600 requires $-OH$ or $-NH$.

Ethanol could be suggested by the 3200-3600, but lacks a strong absorption at 1050-1410, so eliminate ethanol.

The strong peak at 1700 suggests acid or amide $C=O$.

The lack of strong absorption between 2500-3000 eliminates carboxylic acid, so the answer must be: ethanamide!

This process is only possible because it is a multiple choice question. In the actual world, a sample would be analyzed thusly:

1. if it's ethylene, it will be in a gas sample tube, and has a recognizable odor.
2. if it is ethanol, it evaporates quickly, and has a recognizable odor.
3. if it is ethanamide, it evaporates slowly and has a fishy odor.
4. if it is ethanoic acid, it smells like vinegar.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to James's answer, you can often tell primary amines and amides apart from OH groups because they will have two peaks in the 3300 - 3500 region. Your sample clearly shows this double peak, suggesting an NH<sub>2</sub> group. Combined with the strong c=o absorbance at 1700 and you have an amide.

[image]